# Tile map producing wierd layouts

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, 2d

Im trying to sort out my tile map for my 2d tile based game and have hit a rut!

Im using javascript and html5's canvas to build the game.
Im using Tiled editor to build my maps. saving them as .tmx files
After the map is built i copy the array data into javascript like so :

```
function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return  [
            [1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [17,18,19,20,19,20,19,20,21,22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [33,34,35,36,35,36,35,36,37,38,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [49,50,51,52,51,52,51,52,53,54,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,197,198,199,1,1,1,1],
            [65,66,67,68,146,147,67,68,69,70,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,216,217,1,1,1,213,214,215,1,1,1,1],
            [81,82,83,161,162,163,164,84,85,86,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,232,233,1,1,1,229,230,231,1,1,1,1],
            [97,98,99,177,178,179,180,100,101,102,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,1,248,249,1,1,1,245,246,247,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,238,1,1,1,1,239,240,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [216,217,254,1,1,1,1,255,256,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [232,233,1,1,1,117,118,1,1,1,220,1,1,119,120,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1],
            [248,249,1,1,1,133,134,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,216,217,1,1,1,1,1,1,60,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,232,233,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,248,249,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,220,1,1,1,1,1,1,216,217,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,149,150,151,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,232,233,1,1,1],
            [12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,1,1,1,1,165,166,167,1,1,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1,248,249,1,1,1],
            [28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,1,1,1,1,181,182,183,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [44,44,44,44,44,15,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,197,198,199,1,1,1,1,119,120,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,216,217,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,213,214,215,1,1,1,1,135,136,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,232,233,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,229,230,231,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,248,249,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,245,246,247,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,197,198,199,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,213,214,215,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,60,1,1,1,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,229,230,231,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,220,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,245,246,247,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,60,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        ];
    }
}
```

I have all my different tiles in a folder, which i load using this loop :

```
for (x = 0; x <= 256; x++) {
    var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
    imageObj.src = "images/prototype/"+x+".jpg";
    mapTiles.push(imageObj);
}
```

And here is my loop to display the map :

```
 for (x = 0; x <= viewWidth; x++){
            for (y = 0; y <= viewHeight; y++){
            var theX = x * 32;
            var theY = y * 32;
            context.drawImage(mapTiles[board[x+viewX][y+viewY]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
        }
    }
```

For some reason when i open the game instead of seeing the map i produced in tiled:

[image: tiled map]

i get this as my map instead :

[image: actual game]

DO you guys have any ideas as to why this is happening>

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.drawImage(mapTiles[board[x+viewX][y+viewY]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
```

I don't know what viewX and viewY are, but have you tried:

```
context.drawImage(mapTiles[board[y+viewY][x+viewX]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
```

You may also have x's and y's reversed in other places.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and that did sort it out, so thanks. So what difference does that make to the way the board is printed? Also my collision detection has know gone very wrong and is making the player collide to blocks that arent there which it thinks it is etc?Any Ideas?

Comment: The difference is that the first index gets you the row in the board array, the second index will be the column. I guessed that the row was the y and the column the x. As to your question with collisions, ask another question on the site and post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Here is a link to the relevent question if you would be as kind to look at it please: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45364/collision-detection-problems-javascript-canvas-game